# Solving an equation $x\cdot e^{(x-C)^2}=1$

Tags: lambert-w, gaussian

I would like to solve the following equation: $$x\cdot e^{(x-C)^2}=1.$$ I tried to use Lambert W function but unsuccessfully. Is there any way to get an exact (or approximate for some non-zero $C$) solution to the equation above?

My attempt was to reduce it to the form of $\tau \cdot e^\tau = B$ which can be solved as $\tau = W(B)$. Yet the $-C$ term in the exponent does not allow me to do this and the trick works only for $C=0$.

Comment: I believe a solution with the Lambert $W$ function for $C\neq0$ is not possible since you have a quadratic polynom in the $\exp$ and multiply the exponential function with a linear polynom.

Comment: For $C=0$, I assume the trick you mean is squaring both sides and multiplying by $2$... which gives $2x^2 e^{2x^2}=2$, or $2x^2=W(2)$, or $x=\sqrt{W(2)/2}$.  But you’re right that this doesn’t obviously extend to $C\neq 0$...

Comment: @mjqxxxx Exactly.

Comment: @lonestudent This only covers the case $C=0$. And [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xe%5E%28x%5E2%29%3D1%2C+solve+for+x) can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by OP, this can be solved for $C=0$ by squaring both sides and multiplying by $2$, yielding
$$
2x^2 e^{2x^2}=2,
$$
or $2x^2=W(2)$, or $x=\sqrt{W(2)/2}\approx 0.652919$.  For $C=1$, of course, the solution is $x=1$.  More generally, note that the solution is a fixed point of
$$
f(x) = \exp\left(-(x-C)^2\right);
$$
since this function is a contraction of $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(0,1]$, it has a *unique* fixed point, and iterating $x\rightarrow f(x)$ (starting at $0$, say) will rapidly converge to the solution for any $C$.  In particular, the initial iterate of $e^{-C^2}$ is an excellent approximation for even moderately large $|C|$... it differs from the exact solution by less than $10\%$ for $C=\pm 2$, by about $1\%$ for $C=\pm 2.5$, and by less than $0.1\%$ for $|C|\ge 3$.

---

Expanding in powers of $x$, we have
$$
x e^{(x-C)^2}=xe^{C^2}e^{-2Cx + x^2}=1,
$$
or
$$
xe^{C^2}=e^{2Cx-x^2}=1+(2Cx-x^2)+\frac{1}{2!}(2Cx-x^2)^2+\frac{1}{3!}(2Cx-x^2)^3+\ldots.
$$
This has a self-consistent asymptotic solution of $x \sim e^{-C^2}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}b_k(C)e^{-kC^2}$, where the coefficients are polynomials in $C$ and can be found by substitution and equating like terms.

Comment: Thanks @mjqxxxx ! Indeed, it is a contraction mapping so an iterative algorithm can give a numerical solution in a few number of steps. I am wondering how did you end up with $e^{-C^2}$ being a good approximate? And how can we show that for large $C$ it is close to the fixed point?

Comment: I see that it is a good approximate, since $x\to 0$ as $C\to \infty$ and we can ignore $x^2$ and $x$ factors in the exponent, but is there any smart way to show measure the approximation error?

Answer (score 0):

Beside numerical methods, you can obtain an approximation of the solution od
$$x\, e^{(x-c)^2}=1$$ at least when $c$ is large enough.

Expanded as a series around We have
$$x\,e^{(x-c)^2}=e^{c^2} \sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n P_n(c)\, x^{n+1} +O(x^{p+1})$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(c) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 c \\
 2 & 2 c^2+1 \\
 3 & \frac{4 c^3}{3}+2 c \\
 4 & \frac{2 c^4}{3}+2 c^2+\frac{1}{2} \\
 5 & \frac{4 c^5}{15}+\frac{4 c^3}{3}+c \\
 6 & \frac{4 c^6}{45}+\frac{2 c^4}{3}+c^2+\frac{1}{6} \\
 7 & \frac{8 c^7}{315}+\frac{4 c^5}{15}+\frac{2 c^3}{3}+\frac{c}{3} \\
 8 & \frac{2 c^8}{315}+\frac{4 c^6}{45}+\frac{c^4}{3}+\frac{c^2}{3}+\frac{1}{24} \\
 9 & \frac{4 c^9}{2835}+\frac{8 c^7}{315}+\frac{2 c^5}{15}+\frac{2
   c^3}{9}+\frac{c}{12} \\
 10 & \frac{4 c^{10}}{14175}+\frac{2 c^8}{315}+\frac{2
   c^6}{45}+\frac{c^4}{9}+\frac{c^2}{12}+\frac{1}{120}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, using series reversion
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^p Q_n(c)\, e^{-n c^2}$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & Q_n(c) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 c \\
 3 & 6 c^2-1 \\
 4 & \frac{64 c^3}{3}-8 c \\
 5 & \frac{250 c^4}{3}-50 c^2+\frac{5}{2} \\
 6 & \frac{1728 c^5}{5}-288 c^3+36 c \\
 7 & \frac{67228 c^6}{45}-\frac{4802 c^4}{3}+343 c^2-\frac{49}{6} \\
 8 & \frac{2097152 c^7}{315}-\frac{131072 c^5}{15}+\frac{8192 c^3}{3}-\frac{512
   c}{3} \\
 9 & \frac{1062882 c^8}{35}-\frac{236196 c^6}{5}+19683 c^4-2187 c^2+\frac{243}{8}
   \\
 10 & \frac{80000000 c^9}{567}-\frac{16000000 c^7}{63}+\frac{400000
   c^5}{3}-\frac{200000 c^3}{9}+\frac{2500 c}{3}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Tryng for a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1.5 & 0.170299585094517 &  0.170953214901680 \\
 1.6 & 0.107895033682801 &  0.107929924415624 \\
 1.7 & 0.070212923033771 &  0.070214469092901 \\
 1.8 & 0.046142704232074 &  0.046142759547435 \\
 1.9 & 0.030328358050644 &  0.030328359630533 \\
 2.0 & 0.019818944318480 &  0.019818944354308 \\
 2.1 & 0.012825805020904 &  0.012825805021547 \\
 2.2 & 0.008196886530498 &  0.008196886530498 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xe^{(x-C)^2}=1$$
$$xe^{(x-C)^2}-1=0$$

We see, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^{(x-C)^2}$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$$xe^{(x-C)^2}=1$$
$x\to t+C$:
$$(C+t)e^{t^2}=1$$

In the case of algebraic $C$, this equation is an algebraic equation of both $t$ and $e^t$ with no univariate factor and the equation cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) therefore in this case.

Because the degrees of $t$ in the polynomial factor and in the exponential factor are different and $C\neq 0$, the equation cannot be solved by Lambert W.

But the equation can be solved by Hyper Lambert W:

$$xe^{(x-C)^2}=1$$
$$G((x-C)^2e^{-x};x)=1$$
$$x=HW((x-C)^2e^{-x};1)$$

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)